# how we get difference between two dates in javascript? using drop down list box in html

Tags: javascript

using drop down list box in html

Comment: The question is not very clear. Do you have some computer code?

Comment: Where are the dates? Does the user select two dates in a dropdown, or subtract a known date from that selected from the dropdown?

Answer (score 4):

This will help you, most likely:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

```
Math.ceil((selecteddate.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```